# If XBee modules from Digi use Silicon Labs chips and their stack, why then would I need them?

Tags: smart-home, zigbee

I recently came to know that XBee modules from Digi use Silicon Labs chips and the Silicon Labs ZigBee stack, so I ask, if I can use the Silicon Labs chips directly with Simplicity Studio as well as the ZigBee stack to create a ZigBee device, why would I need to get XBee modules at all?

Silicon Labs have modules as well as the [Mighty Gecko MGM12P Module for Zigbee and Thread](https://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/mesh-networking/mighty-gecko-modules/mgm12p-mighty-gecko-module) which is multi-protocol and provides much more flexibility having 1024kB of flash and 256kB of RAM. This means that instead of having a processor for the application and a separate ZigBee module I can have both the ZigBee connectivity and the application within the same module.

I'm just trying to understand the justification for an XBee module vs a more versatile Silicon Labs module *(on which the XBee modules are based)*.

Comment: I guess its easier using a zigbee module to connect to arduino(and other development boards) to make prototypes. Just the ease factor though.